# AdView null pointer

Tags: android, admob

I have a custom list view with an adview in it. I get a nullpointer error at atview.setVisibility()

```
.
.
.
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="my id"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:refreshInterval="30"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

.

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_content);
        adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set the ad unit in the `ListView`, like, is it a row in the list, or added as a header/footer?

If it is a row, then you should find the id of that row, extract the entire row in a separate view, and using this view find the reference to the `AdView`

With other words, assuming the AdView is always the first element in the list, you would do:

```
View row = listView.getChildAt(0);
AdView adview = (AdView)row.findViewById(R.id.adView);
```